# javascript replace string individual

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The Example

```
Red Color Or Black Color
```

if i would replace `or` string with `and` using this code

```
var k = "Red Color Or Black Color";
var s = k.replace("or","and");
alert(s);
```

The Result : `Red Coland and Black Coland`

I Want To Replace `or` Only ..

Comment: What is the problem? You can use `k.replace(/\sor\s/i," and ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replace insensitively, make use of regex and use `ignoreCase`(`i`) flag also use word-boundaries. The string version replaces only the first occurrence and is case-sensitive.

If you want to replace all `"or"` regardless of their case, add `g` to the regex.

```
var k = "Red Color Or Black Color";
var s = k.replace(/\bor\b/gi,"and");
alert(s);
```

Comment: @KarimMamdouh check now.

Comment: Oh Sorry I Forget To Use ignoreCase + Global .. anyway thanks it working greatly :D

Comment: @KarimMamdouh why would you do that? It returns the index, which isn't what's needed.

Comment: i'm using jQuery too .. for example 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
    var val = this.value;
 if ( this.value.indexOf("wrong") !== -1 ) {
     this.value = this.value.replace("wrong","right");`